# SQL: A count inside a case inside a case perhaps?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Good day all.

below is an image relating to what I am attempting to achieve.

In one table there is two fields one is an ID and one is a Type.

I figured a picture paints a thousand words, so check the below

I have tried a few things with case and other things but none worked.

There is a couple of things to note: We cannot use temporary tables, inserts or deletes due to certain limitations.

[image: Because using CTRL + K does not work in this situation]

Data Sample:

```
ID  Type
3   bad
2   zeal
4   tro
3   pol
2   tro
2   lata
4   wrong
3   dead
2   wrong
3   dead
4   wrong
3   lata
2   bad
2   zeal
```

Comment: Please provide your query... and small data sample.

Comment: @ Devart, at this point I scrapped every query I tried, I'll attach a data sample.

Comment: And what would be the expected result?

Comment: @papatoob can you see the screenshot?

Comment: Check up on CASE syntax.

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen I am so glad you said that, I typed Cast instead of case.

Comment: @dansmith I can, but I was wandering where the first column (Type 1, Type 2, ...) came from and what actual numbers you'd expect in the result fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you need a table containing the type groups:

```
type    typegroup
bad     1
tro     1
zeal    1
dead    2
lata    2
wrong   2
pol     3
```

Then join, group by type group in order to get one result line per type group and count.

```
select 
  tg.typegroup, 
  count(case when id = 2 then 1 end) as id2,
  count(case when id = 3 then 1 end) as id3
  count(case when id = 4 then 1 end) as id4
from typegroups tg
join mytable m on m.type = tg.type
group by tg.typegroup
order by tg.typegroup;
```

**UPDATE**: Of course you can create such table on-the-fly.

```
...
from
(
  select 'bad' as type, 1 as typegroup
  union all
  select 'tro' as type, 1 as typegroup
  union all
  ...
) tg
join mytable m on m.type = tg.type
...
```

And you can move this to a WITH clause if you prefer so.

Comment: is there anyway you can think of doing this without a new table? at this point though your answer is looking like the most viable.

Comment: Sure, see my update. (Of course you could as well group on a case expression `case when type in ('bad','tro'...`), but that would be less readable in my opinion).

Comment: Does this approach take into account the different type groups in the first result line for Koopa, Gumba and Toadstool?

Comment: @papatoob: Yes, it seems that Koopa, Gumba and Toadstool are mere names for ID 2, 3, and 4. Simply other column alias names instead of my id2, id3, and id4.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Yes, I got this, but the `WHERE Type IN (...)` part in the first result line of the image differs for ID 2, ID 3 and ID 4. It contains different type lists in each of the respective columns. But then again it seems the answer is accepted :)